# Need to create a properties file through gradle which stores the same key value pair as obtained in BuildConfig.java file

Tags: android, gradle

I need to read key value pair which 
**BuildConfig.java** file fetches from gradle example BuildConfig.java contains:

```
public static final String FLAVOR = "aosp";
public static final int VERSION = 2356;
```

so I need create a dev.properties file displaying these key value pair

```
def prop = new Properties()
def propFile = new File("${project.rootDir}/dev.properties")
propFile.createNewFile()
prop.store(propFile.newWriter(),null)
```

Help me what to add in place of null to read the above values from java file

Comment: any reason you want to read them from java file? usually configs for build are defined in gradle file and there you can get them in all your project

Comment: I need to fetch the values and display them in properties file doesn't matter wherever I get them. I am new to this. How do I identify where to fetch the same values from gradle itself ?